# C# Regex command-line argument parsing with single hyphen word wrapping inside argument names

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, command-line-arguments

I am developing an opensource/libre command-line parser for .NET which will be restrictive but clear. It seemed to be an easy task at first but for 2 days being trapped with regex problems, not so fun. :(

I've been reading hours of tutorials about word matching and grouping but it just doesn't work as I would expect. When something suddenly works and I'm trying to add a new feature to the pattern, sometimes everything fails that worked before.

So basically I'd like to build four different regex patterns and they would be used for multiple purposes:

- parsing users argument list typed in the console
- checking argument names defined by the programmer whether they match
  the criteria

Each of the matching patterns would allow one specific class of argument described below:

### 1. Single hyphen prefixed options

A single hyphen must be followed by a single lower/upper case alphanumeric or multiple switches may be grouped.

For example, valid formats:

```
-A
-g
-1
-Ag1
```

The latter is equivalent with the first 3 options grouped together. The following pattern works on the single letters **but unfortunately picks up pieces from other arguments with single hyphen word wrapping**.

```
-{1}\b[A-Za-z0-9]{1}\b
```

### 2. Double hyphen prefixed options

Double hyphens must be followed by at least one lowercase alphabets, which must be followed by multiple lowercase alphanumeric and words can be wrapped by a single hyphen.

For example, valid formats:

```
--valid
--th1s-is-also-val1d
--match-this-option-as-well
```

Invalid formats:

```
--9this-is-invalid-because-of-the-leading-digit
--this--is--invalid--because--of--word--wrapping--by--multiple--hyphens
--this-should-also-fail-because-of-the-trailing-hyphen-
```

These are my latest *broken patterns* for this task. They match on some of the invalid ones as well:

```
-{2}\b[a-z][a-z0-9-]{2,}\b
-{2}\b[a-z][a-z\d]{2,}\b(-{1}[a-z\d]+)*
```

### 3. Values

Must follow a double hyphen option with an equation sign in between them. Only numeric values can omit the double quotation marks.

### 4. Internal commands

Must start with lowercase alphabets, must be followed by multiple lowercase alphanumeric and words can be wrapped by a single hyphen. Basically the same rule applies as described in #2 with the exception of no double hyphen prefix is needed.

I was unable to come up with anything useful for the last two problems until the first two get resolved.

BTW I'm using Monodevelop's built-in Regex toolkit which uses Mono libraries. Could that also be a problem?

And this is my test input that contains all the above samples:

```
-A -g -1 -Ag1 --valid --th1s-is-also-val1d --match-this-option-as-well --9this-is-invalid-because-of-the-leading-digit --this--is--invalid--because--of--word--wrapping--by--multiple--hyphens --this-should-also-fail-because-of-the-trailing-hyphen- --load-file="ReAdMe2.TxT"
```

Could somebody please check my partially working patterns what's wrong with them?

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: so you want to match all the words given in the last ex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add start and end anchors to your second regex.

```
^-{2}\b[a-z][a-z\d]{2,}\b(-[a-z\d]+)*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sS2hN0/1)

**OR**

Use lookarounds.

```
(?<!\S)-{2}\b[a-z][a-z\d]{2,}\b(-{1}[a-z\d]+)*(?!\S)
```

`(?<!\S)` negative lookbehind which asserts that the match won't be preceded by a non-space character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sS2hN0/3)

Comment: I also tried anchors but apparently it doesn't work in my regex toolkit (Monodevelop/Tools/Regex toolkit...). :( I don't have .NET  right now to try it out. As soon as I add them all fail.

Comment: c# supports also an anchored regex . try lookarounds https://regex101.com/r/sS2hN0/2

Comment: I try it out in my code and come back with the result.

Comment: All right! Now it works! So was it .NETs unique syntax kidding me? :D I tried it so many times but always failed with anchors. Many thanks mate!

Comment: Aw man, I just put it in my code #1, #2 and #4 issue works flawless. I try to build one for the #3 issue as well.

Comment: Sorry mate I am so happy that totally forgot. Yeah, you well deserve it mate. I never would have thought it is so trivial.

Comment: could you ask that part as a separate question. Because it seems like your question is already a huge one.

Comment: I think I can solve it on my own, but if do I get stuck I'll open a new one. Many thanks for your help, again. (I still can't get rid of the grin on my face)